Can we use "unless "with a Verb in negative form in the same clause?
It is often said that unless equals if not. Would it be wrong if we use unless with a negative Verb in the same clause? Example : Unless thé train hadn't broken down, we were sure to arrive on Time.

People sometimes avoid this double negative, that is unless they don't want to avoid it.

Yes, it would be wrong.
You cannot use unless with a negative verb, because the word itself implies a negative.
'You cannot use unless to talk about a situation that results from something not happening' (see the Usage Note here. 'Unless is used to introduce the only situation in which something will take place or be true.'

If the train hadn't broken down, we would certainly have arrived on time.


You can use unless with a negative verb, just not here. Unless he hasn't left, he's still here.

@Lambie - That sounds decidedly odd to me. I would say unless he has left or if he hasn't left.

It can be used with negatives (for instance, Unless he hasn’t heard the sad news, he must be devastated), but it certainly does sound awkward.
